# parallel Bubble sort using openmp

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, bubble-sort

i write a c++ code for Bubble sort algorithm and i dont know how to make it parallel using openmp so please help me .....
this is the code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

int a[40001];
void sortArray(int [], int);
int q=0;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
int x=40000;
int values[40000];
for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    values[i]=rand();
}
cout << "Sorting Array .......\n";
clock_t start = clock();
sortArray(values, x);
 cout << "The Array Now Sorted\n";
printf("Elapsed Time : %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
cout << "\n";
}
 void sortArray(int array[], int size)  
{
  bool swap;
   int temp;
  do
  {
   swap = false;
  for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
   {
   if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
  {
    temp = array[count];
    array[count] = array[count + 1];
    array[count + 1] = temp;
    swap = true;
  }
  }
  }while (swap);
}
```

it takes now about 13 seconds i tried to put 
     ##pragma omp parallel for 
before "for statment" in sortArray method and it didnt make any difference it take also about 13 second .....
so please help me as fast as you can

Comment: You won't be able to parallelise the loop, since each iteration depends on the result of the previous iteration. If you want to speed it up, then use just about any algorithm except Bubblesort. Or, better still, use `std::sort`.

Comment: I think you missed something: you cannot ask several processors to each run on their own iteration, but you can parallelize an iteration. Basically if you have 6 elements [0,1,2,3,4,5], then you can have one processor work on [0,1], one on [2,3] and one on [4,5]. On the next iteration, you have one on [2,3] and one on [4,5] and then you are back to square one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this [Parallel Bubble Sort](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/bubbleSort.htm) algorithm:

```
1.  For k = 0 to n-2
2.  If k is even then
3.     for i = 0 to (n/2)-1 do in parallel
4.         If A[2i] > A[2i+1] then
5.             Exchange A[2i] ↔ A[2i+1]
6.  Else
7.     for i = 0 to (n/2)-2 do in parallel
8.         If A[2i+1] > A[2i+2] then
9.             Exchange A[2i+1] ↔ A[2i+2]
10. Next k
```

> Parallel Analysis
>
> Steps 1-10 is a one big loop that is represented n -1 times. Therefore,
>   the parallel time complexity is O(n). If the algorithm, odd-numbered steps need
>   (n/2) - 2 processors and even-numbered steps require
>   (n/2) - 1 processors.Therefore, this needs O(n) processors.

You can still use a `swap` flag check to stop the routine right before `Next k`.
Of course don't expect great speed improvement without hundreds of physical processors :)